# Bind existing HTML to view model

Tags: knockout.js

I have page with server-built ready HTML, lets say:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

I need to link this elements to view model. By another words after calling `'ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#list')[0])'` I'd like `viewModel` to get its values from existing HTML. So I do the following:

```
<ul id="list" data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="text: title">Item 1</li>
    <li data-bind="text: title">Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

and expect `viewModel` to get `items` array from the elements above. But as a result DOM is cleared.

Comment: We'd need to see your viewModel.

Comment: Can you upload all of your code or a simple demo to the jsfiddle ?

Comment: I haven't seen that feature in the knockout library. You probably need to traverse the DOM yourself to get the values out of the html into your viewmodel. Seems like an interesting feature to have when working with a designer but ther is no backend providing JSON yet.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming there is no way you could just bind the html coming from the server to your view model.

So that would mean you are attempting to reverse engineer a view model from existing HTML you would need to traverse the DOM to produce the result you are looking for.

So rename list with the bindings so your apply bindings has one target:

```
<ul id="list2" data-bind="foreach: Items">
    <li data-bind="text: title"></li>
```

Then you will need to work through your original list of html you couldn't use knockout on and traverse the dom to get the values.

```
    var viewModel = {
       Items= ko.observableArray();
    }

    //select your list
    var list = $('#list');

    //iterate through the children and add to the observable array
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(list.children(),function(i){
        viewModel.Items.push({Title:i.text()});
    }

     //then you can bind the view model to your html that has the knockout bindings

     ko.applyBindings(viewModel, )
</script>
```